# Cannot launch MySQL on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

My Mac is in the version below.

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G20015
```

I have installed MySQL via mysql-5.7.21-1-macos10.13-x86_64.dmg, and put `:/usr/local/mysql/bin` in bash_profile's path, but when I executed MySQL on terminal, I got this error:

liuxiaoqindeMacBook-Air:etc liuxiaoqin$ mysqld start --skip-grant-tables
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Seems like the version doesn't match but the mysql dmg is already the latest GA version. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `mysql.server start` to launch your server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider before trying to install MySQL on El Capitan (MacOS 10.11)

The latest stable version when you use a `.dmg` for this OS is `mysql-5.6.27-osx10.11-x86_64` and maybe that's why `_clock_gettime` symbol is missing when you symlink `mysql-5.7.22-1-macos10.13-x86_64` and export to your path.

Anyway, why don't you try a different way with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_fr)?
If you want to, well you can install a higher MySQL version >= 5.7.*

So run :

```
  $ brew upgrade mysql

  # Do not care about these lines if the first command worked fine (cf. this issue)
  $ git -C "$(brew --repo)" fetch --tags
  $ brew update --force
  $ brew install mysql
```

Then, you'll be able to launch the server by typing :

```
  $ brew services start mysql
  ==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
  $ mysql -uroot -p
```

Tips : If you don't have any client yet, give a shout to [SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)...